# Does "$_REQUEST['edit']['term']" make sense?

Tags: url, request

I'm poking through some old code and I came across this:

```
if ($_REQUEST['edit']['term']) {
// do something
}
```

How would the URL look to get the "do something" code to run? I can't come up with anything that works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't that do?

```
<input type="hidden" name="edit[term]" value="1" />
```

Comment: Could be. I was just wondering if the URL could have parms to make the code run.

Comment: Try if http://host/page.php?edit[term]=1 works (maybe you need to urlencode `[]`.